# How to recolor a large collection of svg icons rapidly

Tags: svg, icons

How to recolorer a large collection of SVG icons in a few clicks?

Comment: Use XSLT, you can write code to change most anything.

Answer (score -1):

I had a few dozen SVG icons that I needed to recolor. I started looking into automating the task and ended developing a generic free web app that can do that in a few clicks.
It is available here: [svg recolorer](http://svg.cab63.com)